# Collecting data from a view while it's loaded on the page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is about asp.net mvc3 application razor view. I'm implementing a custom image gallery where the user can delete already existing images. Due to other demands I should not delete the image when the user clicks delete, instead - I just remove the span where the image is located, but I have to somehow save the Id of the image and later on pass it to a service which do all the work on deleting, saving and so on.

The problem I have is that I can't find a way to save multiple values throughout the lifecycle of the view. I tried this - initializing `List<long> idToBeDeleted = new List<long>();` at the begining of my controller and then to use it in my actual method :

```
public void DeletePicture(long documentImageID)
        {
            if (documentImageID != null)
            {
                idToBeDeleted .Add(documentImageID);
            }
        }
```

I tried to declare it on other places too but it seems everything in the controller is reinitialized on each call from the view - I may not be right, in fact it doesn't seem right to me, but for now I see things that way. So my questions is, how to collect those id's and pass them to the controller when the whole form is submitted (this whole thing is inside form) can it be done with C# or I have to search for some client side solution and what could it be?

Comment: Razor happens server side.

Comment: Also, the controller is created per request, so it is stateless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, MVC is stateless. You could approach this from an AJAX angle:

- Create an action that will set a "ToBeDeleted" field related to an Image to be true. As you mentioned, you could then have a service delete all these images later.
- Use an AJAX call on the delete button to give the ID of the image to this controller.
- On success, hide the image/div.
- Only display Images that aren't waiting to be deleted on the page refresh.

Comment: Thanks. I was almost going to start implementing your idea but what do you think about keeping this in session variable? Isn't this better? And easier :)

Comment: Assuming that you're using a database, and the service to delete the images is also running on that server - it will need to know at some point which images need to be deleted, it might as well be straight away. Could be trickier to use session. 

An added benefit of using an AJAX approach is that it will have a more "responsive" UI.